# Reading values out of a byte array in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm quite new to Swift and I'm having some problems to read some information out of a byte array received from SwiftSocket

XCode says : "data [Byte]? 13 values"

[68, 65, 84, 65, 44, 55, 0, 0, 0, 146, 192, 236, 66]

The Response should be something like
"DATA," (68, 65, 84, 65, 44) then an integer 55 (55, 0, 0, 0) followed by a Float (146, 192, 236, 66)

How do I read these values out of the array in Swift3?

```
        let (data, _, _) = client.recv(13)            
        dump(data)            
        var subAr = data?[9...12]
        dump(subAr)
```

This shows me the array but I cant seem to read the values.

```
        let float2 = subAr.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } as Float
```

Gives me the following error: Value of type 'ArraySlice?' has no member 'withUnsafeBytes'

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } as SomeType` is an idiom which works well with `Data`.

Try this:

```
//sample data...
var data: [UInt8]? = [68, 65, 84, 65, 44, 55, 0, 0, 0, 146, 192, 236, 66]

let int32Data = Data(data![5..<9])
let int32Value: Int32 = int32Data.withUnsafeBytes{$0.pointee}
print(int32Value) //->55
let floatData = Data(data![9..<13])
let floatValue: Float = floatData.withUnsafeBytes{$0.pointee}
print(floatValue) //->118.37
```

Assuming the data contains multi-byte values in native endianness (little endian for all Swift-supported platforms as for now). This may not be a good assumption for portability.